# OpenCV Python, release video after aborting on android

Tags: python, opencv, termux

I use Termux to work with Python on my android 10 phone. I managed to install OpenCV in Termux.
I have a script that generates a video and then has to be released, `video.release ( )`

Unforunately, I forgot to release it and opening it in "My Files" says "Failed to play video, an unknow error has occured"

In Linux I was able to repare it with

```
>>> import cv2
>>> video = cv2.VideoCapture ( "video.mp4" )
>>> video.release ( )
```

But on android I am not able to use VideoCapure, it says, my GStreamer is not having required plugins.

What is the workaround or is it possible to fix the issue with GStreamer?

Comment: can't you copy file on computer with Linux and repaire it ? And next time remeber to `release` it on Android.

Comment: @furas well, that's what I am doing now. I have an algorithm, that I coded in big hurry amd so it contains many errors. last time it generated the video for 3 hours and then aborted because of List Index error

Comment: maybe you should put all code in  `try/except` to catch all problems and run `release()`

Comment: @furas, yeah, already fixed all the issues, but I still can't use the generated video :) But I think, I already found an answer for my problem, will check tomorrow

Comment: OpenCV is not a video file repair utility. use ffmpeg to try to repair the video. it may be impossible if the video contains more than just one stream. I would highly recommend NOT using an mp4 container. use an MPEG transport stream, or ".ts" file. that doesn't corrupt from simply killing the process.

Comment: @Christoph Thank you! What fourcc should I use for *.ts video format? I tried to search in Wikipedia and other forums, but none of them worked :(

Comment: the "fourcc" specifies the codec. the file extension specifies the container format. both are separate. I'd suggest MJPG because it's reasonably simple to encode even without hardware acceleration.

Comment: @Christoph Thank you!!